# Get branches coverage on Visual Studio

Tags: c, unit-testing, cobertura, coverlet

Using the CodeCoverage of Visual Studio I'm not able to see the branches coverage results. What would be the best way to get it ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Visual Studio on Windows, you can use the [Fine Code Coverage](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=FortuneNgwenya.FineCodeCoverage) extension. Visualization is updated when you run unit tests inside Visual Studio.